# memory adresses instead of append in list manipulation (poker)

Tags: python, list, append

thank you for even reading this!

so here flop = list of three cards and 
list_of_players  is a list that has two cards in every index

my code is trying to add the three flop cards to each index of list_of_players so that each index represents a pre turn post flop hand

```
from pokerset import poker_hand, deck

working_deck = deck()

list_of_players = [6]
number_of_players = len(list_of_players)
cards=2

flop = []
for i in range(3):
    flop.append(working_deck.get_card())

list_of_players = [[working_deck.get_card() for i in range(2)] for i in range(6)]
print list_of_players

print flop


for i in range(6):
    list_of_players[i].append(flop[i] for i in range(3))

print list_of_players
```

but when I print list of players the output is

```
[[4-Diamonds, 3-Diamonds, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125780>], [10-Clubs, 10-Hearts, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125820>], [Queen-Hearts, 2-Diamonds, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125870>], [Jack-Diamonds, 2-Spades, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1021258c0>], [Ace-Clubs, Ace-Spades, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125910>], [3-Spades, 7-Spades, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125960>]]
```

[Finished in 0.0s]

the interpretation of which is beyond my understanding, could someone please take some karma from me and in return give me some advice?

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, `flop[i] for i in range(3)` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).  You are putting that generator at the end of the loop, and it shows up as something like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x102125780>`.  What you want instead is to append each value that the generator produces.  To do that, use `.extend()`:

```
for i in range(6):
    list_of_players[i].extend(flop[i] for i in range(3))
```

Comment: that is amazing thank you man, extend works lovely, so in essence what it does is that instead of appending each value with a list that it generates from the flop list, itll add onto an existing list within a list, the values that the generator cimes up with! thank you very much g!

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
list_of_players = [6]
```

to

```
list_of_players = [0]*6
```

because that line doesn't look very good.

In your last for loop, you should try this

```
for i in range(6):
    list_of_players[i].append([flop[i] for i in range(3)])
```

When you don't put '[]' around your comprehension expression, it creates a generator expression and not a list.
I hope this will help.

Comment: hey thanks man, ive done that but what happens now is that  every index in list_of_players has two cards and a list of three cards, which will create problems when I feed them to the hand evaluation function which only takes a list of individual cards

Comment: in that you'll just have to use .extend() instead of append.